# How to initialise Main class arguments inside another function? (I'm beginner) Code recommendations

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

```
 package com.example.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        inputListner(MainActivity())

    }
}

fun inputListner(activity: MainActivity){
    // finding the edit text
    val editText = activity.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.link)
    val showButton = activity.findViewById<Button>(R.id.generate)

    // Setting On Click Listener
    showButton.setOnClickListener {

        // Getting the user input
        val text = editText.text

        // Showing the user input
        Toast.makeText(activity, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

I' trying to divide my code a little bit.
The first thing that i wanted to do, is to make a function that would process my button and editText. As i understand i need to pass somehow the argument of the class to the function.

Actually this code compiles, but on my phone it crashes.

than i did another thing:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.link)
        val showButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.generate)
        val MAContext: Context = this@MainActivity
        inputListner(showButton, editText, MAContext )

    }
}

fun inputListner(showButton: Button, editText: EditText, context: Context){
    // finding the edit text


    // Setting On Click Listener
    showButton.setOnClickListener {

        // Getting the user input
        val text = editText.text

        // Showing the user input
        Toast.makeText(Context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Here i need to pass a Context, but i'm getting this error:

**Classifier 'Context' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here**

I'm actually a bit confuse, because it's my first time writing an application and using Kotlin.

Is it necessary to do such things? Does it an appropriate way to divide tasks in the application?

How would you recommend me to structure my code in future?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must never instantiate an Activity class yourself. That is for the operating system to manage and do on your behalf. On this line of code, you are instantiating a brand new instance of your MainActivity by calling its constructor:

```
 inputListner(MainActivity())
```

This doesn't make sense. You don't need a new activity instance. You need to be working with the one the OS gave you, so you could change it to:

```
inputListner(this)
```

In this case `this` is the MainActivity instance you are already "in". It's where the code is that's calling it.

However, your basic approach is a little weird and convoluted. A function that works with pieces of an Activity's UI doesn't need to be outside that Activity. You should move the function inside the Activity, and then it doesn't need a MainActivity argument:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        inputListner()

    }

    private fun inputListner(){
        // finding the edit text
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.link)
        val showButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.generate)
    
        // Setting On Click Listener
        showButton.setOnClickListener {
    
            // Getting the user input
            val text = editText.text
    
            // Showing the user input
            Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

It is also convention to name a function based on what it does, so the name should start with a verb. `inputListner` should probably be named something like `setUpShowButtonBehavior`.

---

In the second part of your question, the error you're getting is because you tried to use capital-C `Context` as if it were a variable, property, or function argument. You need to be careful about capitalization. Your function argument's name is lowercase-C `context`.

Comment: Really cool. 
Thank you! All works)
I'm just started, and still need a bit of guidance on some code aspects. 